# Cannot run styleguidist along side with laravel development server

Tags: laravel, reactjs, documentation-generation, react-styleguidist

I am trying to document my **React Components** and I am running *styleguidist server* along side with *Laravel development server* but the *styleguidist server* crashes with this error.

```
You have another server running at port 6060 somewhere, shut it down first

You can change the port using the `serverPort` option in your style guide config:
https://react-styleguidist.js.org/docs/configuration.html
```

I have configured the *styleguidist server* to run at port *6060* as to resolve this issue and succeeded to run the server only once. After that I am getting this issue again.

How can i resolve this??

Answer (score 2):

The error is saying you have something else running at that port. Have you tried a different one? If you are running a UNIX system, you can see what is running on that port with:

```
lsof -i tcp:6060
```